# Azure cannot see any roles to assign

Tags: azure

I am trying to assign a job role "Cognitive Services OpenAI User" to a service. However, I only see a blank list. I can also assign an owner role, which is too general. I have owner access to the subscription and service. What could went wrong? Please help, I am out of ideas.

[empty job roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rcPk.png), [I have owner role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCyq.png)

try to find why cannot assign job function roles

Comment: Hi, @DanielW Do you have a `User Administrator role` in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

After I manually add myself as owner for the resource group, I can see all the roles. Although the owner role is supposed to be automatically inherited from subscription level, we still need to manually add it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. I fixed that by removing condition from subscription level IAM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35742066)