# Unable to View Roles in Storage Account in Azure getting Blank

Tags: azure, azure-storage, access-control, azure-storage-account

When I tried adding roles, I am unable to view any roles in Role assignment section. How can I view them?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a User Administrator role in your environment?

Comment: I am the one who have created with my account in a Free tier Azure. is there any specific access to be checked

Comment: @Naveen check the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to View Roles in Storage Account in Azure: Getting Blank

According to this **[MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles)**, to assign **roles** to any resource in the Azure Portal, you must have either **`Owner`** or **`User Access Administrator`** roles on your Azure subscription.

The roles containing **`Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write permissions`** enable role assignments, with the Global Administrator having the authority to make these assignments. To obtain these permissions, reach out to someone holding the **`Global Administrator`** or **`Privileged Role Administrator`** role.

In my environment, I assigned the User Access Administrator role at the subscription level.

**Portal:**
[image]

Now, I can view roles in the role assignments in the Storage Account.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Azure cannot see any roles to assign - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77332320/azure-cannot-see-any-roles-to-assign) by DanielW.
2. [Assign Microsoft Entra roles to users - Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/manage-roles-portal)